# unusual behavior copying files to USB memory stick

Tags: usb, files, copy, copy-and-paste

I am attempting to copy about 188GB of files from my Ubuntu 22.04 HD onto a 1TB memory stick. The stick is writable by the system, in that about 50% of the files I wish to copy HAVE been copied each time I've tried this process. I always unmount and eject the stick before physically removing it from the system.

A check using "Properties" indicates that the total number of files to be copied is about 29.9K.

The failure mode is that all of the folders are copied, but some/none of the files and folders within those "top level" folders are copied.

I am using "copy" and "paste" to perform this action.

I've tried this process three times. Each time it fails at a different point, so (it would seem) I'm not running into any sort of a hard limit i.e. out of free space. The stick indicates that it is only 33% full after a failure, that with about 50% of the files on it. So, I would think that there's plenty of room left for the remainder of the material, the portion that failed to copy.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Silly question, but what is the brand model of the memory stick? Are your sure it’s a legit 1TB device and not a firmware-hacked scam device like found on Amazon and eBay?

Comment: "df" reports 1024GB capacity. I do not know how to evaluate whether or not it's fully legitimate. It's some unknown name Chinese brand, not SanDisk or the like, because I wanted to spend $25 and not $130.

If it reports 1TB to the OS, is it possible that it's really not? If so, how can I test that case?

Comment: BTW, gparted reports that the stick file system is exfat, no file system problems exist, and that only 1/3 of the capacity has been used.

Comment: Do you have error messages indicating that the copy is aborted? Be specific on the symptoms you see during copying. And indeed, suspect the quality of the hardware you use. If that is the problem, trowing the device away will be your only option.

Comment: No error messages are ever issued.

Having messed with the memory stick some more, I'm becoming more convinced over time that it's a hardware problem, As [matigo] pointed out earlier, evidently Amazon is selling a lot of junk hardware, and that's where this came from.

Thanks for your reply. If I don't make some headway on this soon, Amazon is going to get this unit back.

Answer (score 5):

As of the time of this answer (November 2023), a 1TB USB stick that sells for less than $90 should be viewed with suspicion of being fake. By "fake", I mean that the firmware in the stick that reports the device's overall capacity has been modified to report a much higher value than is available. Sometimes you will find deals that will sell high capacity sticks at affordable prices but an old bit of wisdom must be followed: *If something appears too good to be true, it probably is.*

Fortunately, there are tools available that will allow you to test the actual capacity of your USB stick. I generally use Fight Flash Fraud, otherwise known as `f3`.

Here's how to use it:

0. Open a terminal (if one is not already open)
1. Install `f3`:

   ```
   sudo apt install f3
   ```
2. Wipe your USB stick completely clear of data, ideally by formatting it using a tool of your choice. The USB stick **must** be empty as the `f3` tool will be writing data to determine its actual capacity.
3. Run `f3write` from the terminal:

   ```
   f3write /media/your-usb-stick
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Be sure to replace `/media/your-usb-stick` with the actual mount point.</sub>

   You will see output that looks something like this:

   ```
   jason@carbon:~$ f3write /media/jason/red-sandisk
   Free space: 7.68 GB
   Creating file 1.h2w ... OK!
   Creating file 2.h2w ... OK!
   Creating file 3.h2w ... OK!
   Creating file 4.h2w ... OK!
   ...

   Free space: 0.00 Byte Average writing speed: 68.37 MB/s
   ```
4. Run `f3read` from the terminal:

   ```
   f3read /media/your-usb-stick
   ```

   You will see something like this:

   ```
   f3read /media/jason/red-sandisk
                    SECTORS         ok/corrupted/changed/overwritten
   Validating file 1.h2w       2097152/        0/      0/          0
   Validating file 2.h2w       2097152/        0/      0/          0
   Validating file 3.h2w       2097152/        0/      0/          0
   Validating file 4.h2w       1522744/        0/      0/          0
   ...

     Data OK: 7.68 GB (15628400 sectors)
   Data LOST: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
                  Corrupted: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
           Slightly changed: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
                Overwritten: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
   Average reading speed: 68.04 MB/s
   ```

   If the `Corrupted` number is anything higher than `0.00`, then your USB stick is not what it claims to be.

Comment: Thanks!! Great info!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those who offered me help on this problem, especially [matigo]. I established that the problem I described was hardware based, in that the memory stick that Amazon sold me was far below the capacity that they advertised it to be.

To their credit, they immediately refunded my purchase price, so "all" I lost was several hours jacking with the POS they sold me.

The lesson learned, as [matigo] pointed out, is that more often than not when you buy cheap stuff, what you get is cheap stuff.

Again, thanks.

Mike